Moving via text objects
Rather than moving by word (w or W), I would often like to move by text object (in particular, in VimTex, by LaTeX command, corresponding to the text object ac). Is there an easy way to do that?
Of course I know one can move by paragraph {/} or sentence (/), but what about other text objects?
I am imagining something like gk/gl for this way of jumping over a command or to the next one but would like to do this without inventing a regex but instead just exploiting the predefined command text object. (Maybe wellle/targets.vim could be used for the "next" and "previous" features.)
Update
As noted in the comments, my questions is quite similar to this one, but none of the answers there is exactly what I am looking for, though they are helpful.
I am looking for something analogous to w etc. in every way, including that it should work in both normal mode and visual mode, and that it should not overwrite the last command for the purposes of repeating commands with ..

This question is similar to: Is there a way to "move to the beginning of the next text object"?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thank you, I didn't know about that other question. I do think it is what I am looking for. None of the answers there is exactly what I'm looking for, I think, because I want something that really works just like { etc., in particular that works in visual mode as well as normal mode. I'll edit accordingly.

What did you try?

@romainl: I tried the plugin  (vim-ninja-feet), which works great -- with the limitation mentioned. I didn't try the other two answers but saw that their authors 1) note the same limitation or 2) do not claim to answer the general question about text objects, which is what I am interested in.

I would do:
nmap gl vac<Esc>w
nmap gh bvaco<Esc>

Where:

vac select the ac text and move to its end,
<Esc> leave visual mode,
w go to the next word.

And:

b goto the previous word,
vac select the ac text object,
o move to the its start,
<Esc> leave visual mode.


This is a good workaround -- thank you for it, I will definitely make use of it -- but I was hoping for something that also works in visual mode, in other words, completely analogous to the native {/} and (/) commands. I gather from this answer to a related question  (see comment on my question above) that what I am looking for may not be easy.

I also just noticed that this solution does not work as intended. It is great for going to the beginning or end of a command if the cursor is in the middle of that command, or for moving within a single line, but going backward it gets stuck at the beginning of a line and going forward it gets stuck at the end of a line.

It seems that the text objects defined by wellle/targets.vim (in particular the "next" and "previous" features) should be useful for adapting this because they work across lines, but somehow at least with vimtex, those next/previous markers don't pick up \cite commands when they have an optional argument (e.g., vanc skips over a \cite[23]{citekey} command to the next \emph{...} command.
